# NG Admin targetEntity Relationship limited by pagination

Tags: javascript, ng-admin

I have a targetEntity defined for a relationship in my creation view on my User entity, however when the list loads the entities, the api call is including the default paging, so the list is not complete.

```
nga.field('CompanyId', 'reference')
        .label('Company')
        .targetEntity(companies)
        .targetField(nga.field('Name'))
        .validation({required: true}),
```

how can I tell it to load ALL the companies, and not perform pagination.  Note I still want pagination on the companies list page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all of those in futureland the answer is to add .perPage(undefined) to the field definition, and then handle this in the restangularConfiguration, and remove the paging completely :

`nga.field('CompanyId', 'reference')
            .label('Company')
            .targetEntity(companies)
            .perPage(undefined)
            .targetField(nga.field('Name'))
            .validation({required: true})`

`RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor(
    (element, operation, what, url, headers, params, httpConfig) => {
      // PAGINATION
      if (params._page != undefined && params._perPage != undefined) {
        params.$skip = (params._page - 1) * params._perPage;
        params.$top = params._perPage;
      }
      else{

        delete params.$skip;
        delete params.$top;
      }
      delete params._page;
      delete params._perPage;`